# mongodump does not create backup files

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I need to create a database backup of mongo database (all collections).
I went to Command Line Tool page at https://cloud.mongodb.com and copied the command:

[image]

So I run this command in the terminal:

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://LineOf****@lineof****.fmyzn.mongodb.net/LineOf**** --out=testmongo
```

I enter password, it is accepted, then I do not get any files or errors. Terminal is just ready for the next command.

What do I do wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your database name correct? It should show some output if it was actually dumping anything.

If the name was wrong it might not return anything.

```
2022-12-26T15:58:37.043-0700    writing testo.test to backup/testo/testo.bson
2022-12-26T15:58:38.469-0700    [........................]  testo.test  0/1  (0.0%)
2022-12-26T15:58:41.055-0700    [########################]  testo.test  1/1  (100.0%)
2022-12-26T15:58:41.055-0700    done dumping testo.test (1 document)
```

For example, for a database named `testo` the command should look like:

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://user@*****.mongodb.net/testo --out=backup
```

Then, in that case you'd have a folder called `backup` with a `testo` folder inside it with the backup.

Comment: You are right! The name was wrong, I thought that database name is displayed in the title, but I needed to go to the Collection page and database name was there over the all collections. Thank you so much! :)